# JS - Have function repeat until condition met

Tags: javascript, function

this seems simple but I'm still having difficulty (I'm relatively new).

I have a function `replaceNextParameter()` which goes through a string and replaces text between two strings I notate as `sub1` and `sub2`. A string may have 0, 1 or many `sub1` and `sub2` present. I would like it to execute function `replaceNextparameter` until there are no more `sub1` and `sub2` present and return the result.

Here is **my code**:

```
function findAllParametersInString (string, sub1, sub2, parameterAndInputArray) {
    newString = string
    if (newString.indexOf(sub1) > -1 && newString.indexOf(sub2) > -1) {
        newString = replaceNextParameter(sub1, sub2, newString, parameterAndInputArray);
    }
    return newString
};
```

Here is a live **example** of what it should do.

```
//data:
const paramsArray = [
    {param: "company", input: "COMPANY"},
    {param: "url", input: "URL"},
]
const sampleMessage = "BlaBlaBla {{company}} and {{url}}"

findAllParametersInString(sampleMessage,'{{', '}}', paramsArray);
//Should return "BlaBlaBla COMPANY and URL"
```

Any idea how to fix it? Currently it only returns `"BlaBlaBla COMPANY and {{url}}"`

Comment: Look into using a `while` loop. The basic description of your logic is `while condition is true, do something`, which is exactly the kind of problem that a `while` loop is designed for. Recursion is also an option, but is far less efficient and not nearly as readable.

Comment: Thank you @Flemming, I did look into it, but I am not sure how to have it repeat the function AND return the new result each time, any ideas?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I just didn't use it correctly, `while` worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findAllParametersInString (string, sub1, sub2, parameterAndInputArray) {
    newString = string
    while (newString.indexOf(sub1) > -1 && newString.indexOf(sub2) > -1) {
        newString = replaceNextParameter(sub1, sub2, newString, parameterAndInputArray);
    }
    return newString
};
```

Did the trick based off of @Flemming

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use your `param` value as key, and your `input` value as value in one single object. Like this:

```
var params = {
    company: "COMPANY",
    url: "URL"
};
```

and now use this simple function:

```
var sampleMessage = "BlaBlaBla {{company}} and {{url}}";

function replace(str, map) {
    for (var key in map) {
        str = str.split('{{' + key + '}}').join(map[key]);
    }
    return str;
}

replace(sampleMessage, params); // -> "BlaBlaBla COMPANY and URL"
```

You can use parameters for `{{` and `}}` in `replace` function

Comment: Hello Andrea, I appreciate the answer, however my intentions are more complicated than the example shown. The values are irrelevant, thank you for the remark tho! If it was this simple (or the thing I was doing didn't have more "strings attached" I completely agree with your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Although late, yet I hope this solution might be suitable for someone.
The best solution I think, since it's string you want to deal with, is to use regular expression.

Although I'm not sure what the `parameterAndInputArray` is for though.
So I would use this (although a better regex can be created):

```
let newstring = oldstring.replace(/sub1/gi,replacement1).replace(/sub2/gi,replacement2)
```

where `replacement[1/2]` will be the character to be replaced eg(`'@'`) or empty quotes (`''`) if `sub[1/2]` are to be removed.